# Magento Marketplace Popularity score

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, extensions

I am curious about how the popularity score of the Magento Marketplace works. If you hover over it, it says referals to site/downloads.

But consider this screenshot:
[image]

All 4 extensions more or less do the same, 3 of them are free, 1 costs $20. How can I interpret these popularity scores? I can't imagine that everybody buys the extension for $20 if you could get the same for free. There is even one free extension which does more than the $20 one. Why does it have 23k?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one with the high popularity score had it's first release in 2010. Old extensions all have a very high popularity.

You can check this by checking the release notes.

I also suspect that the popularity score calculation used to be different from how it's done currently, causing old extension to have a really high score.

Back in the day, you had to log in first when clicking a link in the extension description text. Nowadays, the links in the extension text are always clickable. These clicks don't count for the popularity score. The clicks on the 'get extension' button do though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe you can provide a way for me how you can find out reliable data of selling numbers for different extensions. For example: I want to know how many times these extensions have been sold. How can I interpret the 23k and the under 100 of the other 3 in regard of selling numbers?

Comment: My pleasure. You can't really know the amount of sales. For example, you don't know if the one that's USD 20 now was free first. Maybe the popularity score is so high because it used to be free. Also, because sales aren't taking place on the platform itself it's not possible to track them. You might be able to do some guesswork but in the end you will never get a really good estimate.

Comment: Also, I think old extension popularity scores are really inflated, but for new ones they are deflated. Virtually every extension we sell has more sales than the popularity score displayed on connect. (even the referral sales from connect are higher than the popularity score)

Comment: Dou you think there is a good chance to start offering extensions for Magento2 as the new Marketplace will be published in November? If you are the first on the new Marketplace who will offer extensions with great ideas, is this profitable? Seems like you work in the extension business, can I ask you some more questions regarding the support expenditure for buyers of these extensions? :-)

Comment: Well for as far as I know Magento 2 is a completely different beast when comparing it to Magento 1. Also I understand that Magento 2 is still changing a lot, so I'm unsure if it's worth to invest your effort in it already. There are also rumors that there will be something like a 30% fee charged per sale through the new connect channel besides that. Regarding the support expenditure, send me an e-mail at info@plugin.company and we can discuss.

Answer (score 1):

There is of course the obvious... I think webshop apps wrote an article that mentions the popularity score issue, Karen also presented about it a while back. Its rumored that the connect is going to really head in the right direction going forward.

http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2014/12/magento-connect-is-a-fraud/

For now get a little more information before engaging connect from triple check.io

http://triplecheck.io/

Answer (score 0):

The popularity score is based on download....means this extension how many time download from the magentcommerce.....
There is no matter this extension how much old....many extension is old but they have no popularity score.......Many extension on magento commerce is not download a single time..but in market they are poular like 
[Mage-world reward point pro](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/reward-points-pro-extension-by-mageworld.html)

as per my knowledge extension popularity is based on how many  time that  download from magento commerce.
And Costing as per vendor...like if you buy reward point platinum  from mage store they will give you in 299$ ... because they have trust of users...so if the vendor is popular they can take you some more money of their good will..in form of money....but mage store reward point platinum have less feature compare then mage-world reward point pro....but mage-world not so popular like magestore so they taking less  money with great feature...as compared to mage-store .

so lastly in my conclusion the popularity is based on no of downloads....and cost is as per vendor market value and extension trust by user....